# Need help with url and rollup image fields in sitepages using SPFX with REST

Tags: rest, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp

I'm new to SPFX and still trying to find my way around.  At the moment I'm struggling to access particular fields from site pages using REST. I realize this is a n00b request, but any help would be apppreciated.

The current requirement is to create a simple web part that will go onto the intranet landing page. It takes a single page URL as a property, validate that the URL uses a specific custom content type, and then display the article date, content type, comments, rollup image and a 'Read more' button linking to the page from the url property.

My current approach is roughly:

```
export interface ISPList { 
  Id: string;
  Url: any;
  PublishingRollupImage: any;
}
```

and

```
private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> { 

  return this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/Items`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
        debugger; 
        return response.json(); 
      }); 
  }
```

This works for the most part, but doesn't include values for the rollup image or url to the page represented by a given listitem.  Suggestions on accessing the fields mentioned, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the new `RenderListDataAsStream` endpoint to get these values.

Microsoft itself uses this endpoint to get data.

It will be a `POST` request where you need to specify the `ViewFields` that you need. These will be the internal names of the columns.

Modify your code from below sample code:

```
const restAPI = `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/RenderListDataAsStream`;
this.context.spHttpClient.post(restAPI, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
  body: JSON.stringify({
    parameters: {
      RenderOptions: 2,
      ViewXml: `<View>
              <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
                <FieldRef Name="PublishingPageContent"/>
                <FieldRef Name="PublishingRollupImage"/>
                <FieldRef Name="ArticleStartDate"/>
                <FieldRef Name="Comments"/>
              </ViewFields>
            </View>`
    }
  })
})
  .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => response.json())
  .then((response: any) => {
    if (response && response.Row && response.Row.length > 0) {
      console.log(response.Row);
    }
  });
```